# M2: Product reviews and configurable products

Tags: magento2

Let's say I sell a bike in two variations (black and white). That's 3 products in total: 1 configurable product and 2 simple products.

When a seller goes to the bike's configurable product page to write a review, the review is assigned to the configurable product. That is not ideal, because Google Merchant Center wants me to export reviews at variation-level. However, if I collect reviews at variation-level, the reviews won't be showing at the configurable product page.

My questions:

- Is it possible to give the visitor an option to leave a review for a specific variation?
- Is it possible to make a configurable product collect all reviews of its attached simple products?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to make a configurable product collect all reviews of
> its attached simple products?

I had a similar issue where I wanted to aggregate product reviews so that reviews submitted for child products were also shown on the configurable parent.

I wrote a module to do this and you can see how it works here :

https://github.com/gaiterjones/Magento2_ProductReviews

This module aggregates product reviews from Grouped associated products or Configurable child products to the parent product. If you have visible child or associated products the reviews for these products will be displayed with the parent product reviews and review summary.

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one running into this issue. I'll check out your module tomorrow. Sounds like your module is the answer to my second question.

If I may ask... concering the first question: how are you collecting reviews for individual child products? Based on your post, not through the product page, I assume?

Comment: If the child product is visible in the catalog then customers can submit reviews to it - these reviews are aggregated up to the parent product.

Comment: I see what you mean, that's not going to work in my situation. My simple products are visible, but redirect to the configurable product with the options pre-selected.

Comment: @Jason did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this problem? I find myself in exactly the situation you described.